# I am trying to display drop down menu items ,but when I hover my cursor on menu item the entire navbar is expanding

Tags: html

I am trying to display drop down menu items, but when I hover my cursor on menu item the entire navbar is expanding.  I have tried with position: absolute and relative.

```
<nav class ="navbar">
<div class="menu-bar">
<div class="dropdown">
 <li class="dropbtn" style ="list-style: none" >Know us</li> 
        
<div class="dropdown-content">
<ul class="sub_menu">
<li><a href=" ">About us</a></li> 
</ul> 
</div>


  .navbar {
   overflow: hidden;        
  }
 .dropdown {
   float: left;
   overflow: hidden; 
 }     
 .dropdown .dropbtn {
  display: inline-block; 
   color: white;
   padding: 14px 16px;
   background-color: inherit;
   font-family: inherit; 
 } 
 .dropdown-content {
   display: none;
   position: relative; 
   min-width: 160px;
   box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   z-index: 1;
  }
  .dropdown-content a {
     float: none;          
     padding: 12px 16px; 
     display: block;         
    } 
   .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide your html as well?

Comment: Please make [mre]

Comment: <div class="menu-bar">
   <div class="dropdown">
   <ul class="menu hidden-xs hidden-sm">
    <li class="dropbtn" style ="list-style: none" >Know us  
    </li> 
   
   <div class="dropdown-content">
    <ul class="sub_menu">
     <li><a href=" ">About us</a></li> 
    </ul> 
    </div> 
    <li class="dropbtn" style ="list-style: none">Services</li>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
     <ul class="sub_menu sub_menu2">
      <li><a href=" ">AI as a Service</a></li> 
     </ul>
    </div> 
   </ul> 
  </div>
  </div>

Answer (score -1):

use flex-box for easy navigation.